# Immediately seeing changes in R shiny UI, in the browser, after making changes in code without having to restart the server?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shinyjs

Is it possible to see the changes in UI (only the UI and not server) after I make changes in my code, without having to restart the server/refresh the page? If cache needs to be cleared, can that also be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reactiveFileReader` to regularly `source` the code you'd save in another file, and `renderUI()`/`uiOutput` to display that dynamic UI:

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- uiOutput("ui")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ui <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, "source.R", source)
  output$ui <- renderUI(ui())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### source.R

```
fluidPage(
  textInput("text", "text"),
  textInput("text2", "text")
  )
```

You still have to find out howto get rid of that "TRUE":
[image: result]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works just fine. I need it only for development purposes.